# Which very large cardinals are preserved under Woodin's forcing for $\mathsf{AC}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Woodin showed that we can force $\mathsf{AC}$ if there is a proper class of supercompact cardinals while preserving supercompacts, by forcing Easton-support iteration of $\operatorname{Col}(\kappa,<V_\lambda)$ with a careful choice of $\kappa$ and $\lambda$:

> **Definition.** Let $\operatorname{Col}(\kappa,<V_{\lambda})$ be the collection of all partial functions $f:\kappa\times\lambda\rightharpoonup V_{\lambda}$ such that $|\operatorname{dom}f|<\kappa$ and $f(\xi,\eta)\in V_{1+\eta}$ for each $\xi<\kappa$ and $\eta<\lambda$.
>
> Define the iteration $\langle \mathbb{Q}_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}, \alpha\ge 1\rangle$ and the sequence of inaccessible cardinals $\langle \nu_\alpha\mid \alpha\in \mathrm{Ord}\rangle$ as follows:
>
> - Assume that there is the least regular cardinal $\gamma_0$ such that $\mathsf{DC}_{<\gamma_0}$ holds but $\mathsf{DC}_{\gamma_0}$ fails. Then $\gamma_0$ is less than the least supercompact cardinal $\delta_0$.
>   Define $\nu_0<\delta_0$ as the least inaccessible such that $\mathbb{Q}_1:=\operatorname{Col}(\omega, <V_{\nu_0})$ forces $\mathsf{DC}_{<\nu_0}$
> - Assume that we have $\langle\mathbb{Q}_\alpha \mid \alpha\le \beta\rangle$ and $\langle \nu_\alpha\mid \alpha<\beta\rangle$. Let $\gamma_\beta=\sup_{\alpha<\beta}\nu_\alpha$.
>   Define $\nu_\beta$ as the least inaccessible such that $\mathbb{Q}_{\beta+1}:=\mathbb{Q}_\beta * \operatorname{Col}(\gamma_\beta,<V_{\nu_\beta})$ forces $\mathsf{DC}_{<\nu_\beta}$.
> - For each limit $\beta$, take $\mathbb{Q}_\beta$ as the Easton limit of $\langle\mathbb{Q}_\alpha \mid \alpha< \beta\rangle$.

(Here $\kappa$ is inaccessible if $V_\kappa$ is a model of second-order ZF. Woodin used *strongly inaccessible* to denote inaccessible cardinals, and called regular limit cardinals inaccessibles.)

Woodin also showed that this proper class forcing preserves supercompact cardinals. If I read Woodin's proof correctly, his forcing also preserves extendible cardinals.
Furthermore, Woodin also showed that $I_1$ is preserved under some assumptions. The precise statement is as follows:

> **Theorem.** Let $\lambda$ be a cardinal witnessing $I_1$ and $\delta>\lambda$ is a supercompact cardinal such that $V_\lambda\prec V_\delta$. If $G$ is $V$-generic filter of the Woodin's forcing, then $j:V_{\lambda+1}\to V_{\lambda+1}$ lifts to $j:V[G]_{\lambda+1}\to V[G]_{\lambda+1}$.

My question is: are which very large cardinals preserved under Woodin's forcing?
I am interested in the following particular cases:

1. $n$-huge cardinals (or super-$n$-huge cardinals), and
2. Wholeness axiom $\mathsf{WA}_n$ (Especially, the case $n=0$.)

Comment: I mean, if you preserve supercompactness, what would be the difference in the case of hugeness?

Comment: @Asaf Sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you asking about the motivation of the question, or the technical difference between supercompactness and hugeness?

Comment: Neither. I'm asking where in the proof of preservation of supercompact cardinals are we using the fact that they are not huge?

Comment: @Asaf As far as I know the preservation of supercompactness uses Lemma 222 of Woodin's *Suitable Extender Model I* (similar to Magidor's characterization of supercompactness), but does it imply a given cardinal is not huge?

Comment: I see. I'd have expected that to be done manually by lifting embeddings and proving the closure directly.